# Cython: How to sort the contents of one vector by another vector?

Tags: python, c++, cython

I'm trying to sort two C++ vectors in Cython, one by the contents of itself and one by the contents of the first vector.

```
cimport cython
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from libcpp.algorithm cimport sort as stdsort

def function():

    cdef vector[np.npy_float] distances
    cdef vector[np.npy_intp] indices

    d = [9., 8., 3., 2., 3.]
    for i in range(len(d)):
        distances.push_back(d[i])
        indices.push_back(i)

    stdsort(distances.begin(), distances.end())
    // distances = [2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 8.0, 9.0]
    // Sort indices by distances?

    return distances, indices
```

I know in pure C++ you can easily do this with an object that houses both the distance and the index and having a custom sorting function for that object, but what's an easy way to do this in Cython?

Comment: Since it sounds like you know how to do it in C++, I think it'd be easiest to just write the C++ code and call it from Cython.

Comment: @DavidW, for the sake of code simplicity, I would love to be able to do it in Cython, but if it's not possible I would have to do it some other way. I can't put the values in pairs and sort the pairs by the first element or something? :(

Comment: I think using pairs would probably work - I think they already have the right comparison functions defined.

Comment: How does `stdsort` differ from Python's `sort`?  If it has the `key=` parameter then this becomes trivial.

Answer (score 3):

For getting sorting indices in C++, one usually would not create a new vector with index-value pairs, but choose a comparator, which would achieve the same without actually copying memory.

Translating this to Cython would look as follows:

```
%%cython -+ -c=-std=c++11
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
cdef extern from *:
    """
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <vector>
    void sort_via_score(std::vector<int>& indices, const std::vector<double>& scores){
        std::sort(indices.begin(), indices.end(),
                  [&scores](int i, int j){return scores.at(i)<scores.at(j);}
                 );
    }
    """
    void sort_via_score(vector[int]& indices, vector[double]& scores)
    
def sort_indices(lst):
    cdef vector[double] scores = lst
    cdef vector[int] indices = range(len(lst))
    sort_via_score(indices, scores)
    return indices
```

The function `sort_indices` is a wrapper which allows us to check the implementation quickly:

```
sort_indices([5,4,3,2,1])
# [4, 3, 2, 1, 0] as expected
```

`sort_via_score` works similar to the following one-liner in Python:

```
def sort_indices_py(scores):
    return sorted(range(len(scores)), key=lambda x: scores[x])
```

the `scores`-vector is used in the closure to look-up the score of the index . There are no new objects created which would put index and its score together in memory - they are combined by logic of the `key`-function alone.

---

The solution above uses verbatim C-code, because it is so much easier to write C++ code with C++ than with Cython.

If one really wants to stick to "pure" Cython (I don't recomend), so it is possible to emulate the C++-closures with the following code:

```
%%cython -+
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from libcpp.algorithm cimport sort as stdsort

cdef vector[double]* vec
cdef bint comp_fun(int i, int j):
    return vec.at(i)<vec.at(j)

def sort_indices2(lst):
    cdef vector[double] scores = lst
    cdef vector[int] indices = range(len(lst))
    global vec
    vec = &scores # "global closure"
    stdsort(indices.begin(), indices.end(), comp_fun)
    return indices
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to take the slightly simpler approach of creating a single array encompassing both scores and indices then sorting that. The downside is that it involves a little more copying that @ead's answer.

For this `std::pair` works pretty well (since it already defines the operators you need) and can readily be accessed from Cython.

```
# distutils: language = c++

from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from libcpp.utility cimport pair
from libcpp.algorithm cimport sort as stdsort

def function():
    cdef vector[pair[float, int]] di
    cdef vector[float] distances
    cdef vector[int] indices
    

    d = [9., 8., 3., 2., 3.]
    for i in range(len(d)):
        di.push_back(pair[float, int](d[i], i))

    stdsort(di.begin(), di.end())
    
    for di_pair in di:
        distances.push_back(di_pair.first)
        indices.push_back(di_pair.second)

    return distances, indices
```

For more advanced cases you might have to define a custom struct or class with its own comparators rather than using `std::pair`. In these cases I wouldn't get too hung up on using Cython for everything - it's generally easier to write C++ in C++. However for this case you don't need to.